# MySQL Sakila Select actor with the most films

Tags: mysql, database, select

I need to select the actor wich appeared in the most films.
I am using the sakila Database 1.0:

```
.mwb (MySQL Workbench): https://www.sendspace.com/file/i0z82j
.sql (schema): https://www.sendspace.com/file/vd3hnu
.sql (data): https://www.sendspace.com/file/gbp9ri
```

What i already have is two queries

1. which selects every actor n times (n=appearances in films).
   My query:
   SELECT actor.first_name, actor.last_name
   FROM actor
   INNER JOIN film_actor
   ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id;

Result:

```
+------------+-------------+
| first_name | last_name   |
+------------+-------------+
| PENELOPE   |GUINESS      | //4 Films in this examle
| PENELOPE   |GUINESS      |
| PENELOPE   |GUINESS      |
| PENELOPE   |GUINESS      |
| NICK       |WAHLBERG     | //5 Films in this examle
| NICK       |WAHLBERG     |
| NICK       |WAHLBERG     |
| NICK       |WAHLBERG     |
| NICK       |WAHLBERG     |
| ED         |CHASE        | //5 Films in this examle
| ED         |CHASE        |
| ED         |CHASE        |
| ED         |CHASE        |
| ED         |CHASE        |
| JENNIFER   |DAVIS        | //4 Films in this examle
| JENNIFER   |DAVIS        |
| JENNIFER   |DAVIS        |
| JENNIFER   |DAVIS        |
| BETTE      |NICHOLSON    | //3 Films in this examle
| BETTE      |NICHOLSON    |
| BETTE      |NICHOLSON    |
| ...        |...          | //Everyother Actor who appeared in a film
+------------+-------------+
```

2. which selects every film a specific actor appeared in.
   My query:
   SELECT actor_id,film_id
   FROM film_actor
   WHERE actor_id = 1;

Result: Actor 1 appeared in 19 films.

```
+----------+-------- +
| actor_id | film_id |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 1       |
| 1        | 23      |
| 1        | 25      |
| 1        | 106     |
| 1        | 140     |
| 1        | 166     |
| 1        | 277     |
| 1        | 361     |
| 1        | 438     |
| 1        | 499     |
| 1        | 506     |
| 1        | 509     |
| 1        | 605     |
| 1        | 635     |
| 1        | 749     |
| 1        | 832     |
| 1        | 939     |
| 1        | 970     |
| 1        | 980     |
+----------+---------+
```

But what i want is:
The actor who appeared in the most films:

```
+------------+---------------+--------+
| first_name | last_name     | films  |
+------------+---------------+--------+
| NICK       | WAHLBERG      | 5      |
| ED         | CHASE         | 5      |
| ...        | ...           | ...    |
+------------+----------------+-------+
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I ve edited the post but i cant give you more (less) because im simply not able to cut a part of this database out. I added the files with wich you can rebuild the entire databese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to run the query on your db I'd do:

```
SELECT count(film_actor.actor_id), actor.first_name, actor.last_name 
FROM actor INNER JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
GROUP BY film_actor.actor_id ;
```

Untested

Comment: It works perfectley fine and is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    T1.first_name, 
    T1.last_name,
    count(*) as films
FROM 
    sakila.actor as T1
left JOIN 
    sakila.film_actor as T2 ON T1.actor_id = T2.actor_id 
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
ORDER BY films desc
```

This query almost covers both of your questions. You can use 'LIMIT' function to only return 1 row

Answer (score -1):

```
select concat(a.FIRST_NAME,' ', a.LAST_NAME) as Full_name
from ACTOR a
left join FILM_ACTOR fa on a.ACTOR_ID = fa.ACTOR_ID
group by a.ACTOR_ID, a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: @MichaelWayne It is an answer, not a question. But it lacks a brief description of what it actually does.